# Internet keeps loading when Ethernet is plugged in with Lubuntu

Tags: ethernet

I installed Lubuntu for the first time ever. I have just moved from Windows and I can not believe how much better it is. Anyway on to the problem I am having. When I plug the Ethernet in the circle just spend until it gives up. On Lubuntu 18.04. I have no WiFi adapter.

Code I get when I input: 
"lspci -knn | grep -A 3 -i ether && sudo lshw -C Network && ip addr"
is as follows: https://pastebin.com/6gNr797d

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu, welcome to Linux. In general the ethernet adapter should work out of the box. While you have been installing Lubuntu did your ethernet adapter work? What is the output of `lspci -knn | grep -A 3 -i ether && sudo lshw -C Network && ip addr`

Comment: Going to have to ask you where I input that line? Very very new to this all.

Comment: sure sorry, in Linux we use a Termial. The same thing that is called cmd.exe in windows. It helps a lot and is a big tool. In Lubuntu it is called lxterminal i think. You should be able to find it when you click "Start" -> "System Tools" or by pressing the keycombination of "CTRL" + "LEFT ALT" + "T"

Comment: Also I am not to sure if it worked when installing. I did not need internet to install Lubuntu. Appreciate your help so far!

Comment: Thank you so much. I shall do this tommorow as I am not near my computer now. I'll input what comes out here.

Comment: post your output inside your question / edit your question. an alternative is to use pastebin.com and than post the link at the end of your question either.

Comment: I edited my post with the pastebin link of what code I get.

Comment: regarding to your output, which by the way looks incomplete `lspci -knn | grep -A 3 -i ether` is missing, your ethernet adapter seems to be loaded properly and you recieve an ip from your router. what happens when you write `ping -c 3 google.com` and `ping -c 3 8.8.8.8`

Comment: I pasted the results of both those lines into pastebin again. Here is the link https://pastebin.com/Pexwisr1

Comment: Also what do you mean my output looks complete?

Comment: Here is the computer I am using just in case you need to check specs or drivers . https://www.cnet.com/products/hp-compaq-d530-small-form-factor/

Comment: Exile, **you need to explain your problem again please**. I thought you have problems with your ethernet connection but all your pastebin's show me that your ethernet adapter is properly installed and working fine.

Comment: When I plug it in I still have no internet connection on anything. Can't load any websites or and apps that require internet.

Comment: It looks like it's struggling a lot to connect. Sometimes it takes about a minute and loads the page but then when I press on something from that page it says can't connect.

Comment: are you able to to an `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install speedtest-cli && speedtest`

Comment: It comes back saying it could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: resource temporary unavailable)

Comment: Next line says unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

Comment: quoting Valtinator from: https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process : You can use `sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock` to find the process that owns the lock file (if empty, assume the lock is left over from a previous boot and can be `sudo rm` removed), then consider doing a `sudo kill -9 <PID>` (get <PID> from lsof output. PID is the process id number. If you kill the right process apt-get should be unlocked.

Comment: I am not able to get past the first step. When I type it in I get this "lsof: WARNING: can't start() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000gvfs.       Output information may be incomplete.

Comment: you can ignore the warning https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171519/lsof-warning-cant-stat-fuse-gvfsd-fuse-file-system if u have no other output it means that no process is blocking apt and you should be able to run the update and install commands i previously suggested (speedtest-cli).

Comment: I can't though. When I run the speed test it gives me the could not get lock error (above it it says reading package list... Done)  and when I run the sudo lsof which was quoted from the other user I still get  the same line of error

Comment: I got it to start downloading. This is the output - https://pastebin.com/0Bjd3PZA

Comment: i dont understand why u can ping google.com but are unable to connect to the update server... whats your output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`? Are you able to reach this website and do the test: http://ipv6-test.com/ Whats your output of `route`

Comment: I am not able to connect to the website.  Here is the output of the cat line - https://ibb.co/LSkJnfR . Also what do you mean what is the output of route? When I just type in route I says command not found.

Comment: looks like in 18.04 the `route` command was replaced. Type `ip route && ip -6 route` is the notebook connected directly with your router? do you know the router ip adress perhaps? Are there any other computer connected to that router? are they able to browse the web? what Operating Systems are you running on them?

Comment: I will do that as soon as I get home but for now I shall answer those questions for you. It is connected directly via a ethernet cable and I believe I do have the ip adress of the router. I have about 7 other computers connected to the internet, 6 of them running Windows and the other one running Lubuntu. Everything works as expected to one all the other devices. This is the only one having problems. Once again thank you for your help.

Comment: Output  of ip route - https://ibb.co/CBQ1bPK

Comment: is your routers internal ip 192.168.1.254? have you ever tried to use a different ethernet port and cable? perhaps your cable or the ethernet port at your router or computer has issues. how can it be that you once can ping google and another time you cant? regarding to your last pictures your link was down - no cable connected for example.

Comment: It's always been in the same port. The cable I am using works on all my other computers and yes I am pretty sure that is the ip

Comment: I hope you have not give up haha

Comment: Hey, no I am sorry, but i have no clue whats wrong. Your OS loads the ethernet device properly. It recieves an IP from your router, it sets the default route via your gateway / router ip. But then, for some reason, it says **link down** as if your cable wouldnt be connected anymore. I have no clue why. The only problem i see is that **autonegotiation is set to off**. Perhaps this is the reason, but i have never dealt with autonegotiation and how to turn it on or off- see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420066/linux-disables-ethernet-auto-negotiation-on-plugging-in-the-cable and